# Detect a class change inside a div using jquery listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, addeventlistener

This is my default code. I want to add a listener to `.variations_div > .select-items > div`. Basically my select is replaced with the divs. I wanted to use select onchange but it is not working now. This is my original HTML.

```
<div class="custom-select variations_div">
   <select>
      <option value="">- Select Variation -</option>
      <option value="9298">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 10MM</option>
      <option value="9299">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 15MM</option>
      <option value="9300">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 20MM</option>
      <option value="9301">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 25MM</option>
   </select>
   <div class="select-selected">- Select Variation -</div>
   <div class="select-items select-hide">
      <div>- Select Variation -</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 10MM</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 15MM</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 20MM</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 25MM</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Basically when I change the select, it adds a class `same-as-selected` to the div. I want the listener to extract the html of that particular div and give it to me.

```
<div class="custom-select variations_div">
   <select>
      <option value="">- Select Variation -</option>
      <option value="9298">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 10MM</option>
      <option value="9299">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 15MM</option>
      <option value="9300">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 20MM</option>
      <option value="9301">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 25MM</option>
   </select>
   <div class="select-selected">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 15MM</div>
   <div class="select-items select-hide">
      <div>- Select Variation -</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 10MM</div>
      <div class="same-as-selected">EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 15MM</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 20MM</div>
      <div>EXT SOCKET 1/2 X 1/2 X 25MM</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my current code.

```
$(".variations_div > .select-items > div").attrchange({
    trackValues: true, // set to true so that the event object is updated with old & new values
    callback: function(evnt) {
        alert(1);
        if(evnt.attributeName == "class") { // which attribute you want to watch for changes
            if(evnt.newValue.search(/open/i) == -1) { // "open" is the class name you search for inside "class" attribute

                // your code to execute goes here...
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Where does `attrchange` come from?  That's not a standard jQuery method

Comment: Truth be told I copied it from somewhere. IDK what it does.

Answer (score -2):

the `change` works here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1r3a258/4/)